# Is there a native Proper Case string function in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I was about to write my own C# extension to convert a string to Proper Case (i.e. capitalize the first letter of every word), then I wondered if there's not a native C# function to do just that... is there?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[There is a function that capitalises the first letters of words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx), though you should see the remarks section as it does have some limitations which may make it unsuitable for your needs.

Comment: But it fails to properly proper case examples such as "o'riley" to "O'Riley", instead producing "O'riley".

Comment: @midspace - As I said, yes there is a function, but you should read the remarks section. This type of edge case is explicitly called out there.

Comment: @midspace Perhaps this is overkill, but I decided to roll my own with `Regex.Replace(input.ToLower(), @"\b[a-z]", m => m.Value.ToUpper())`

Comment: @Michael That is slower than doing a ToLower and then ToTitleCase in my experience.

Comment: @Shawn: I have no doubt that it's slower. It uses a different mechanism and results in different output for the edge case midspace mentioned.

Answer (score 72):

```
String s  = "yOu caN Use thIs"

s = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
           .CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLower());
```

The main limitation I can see with this is that it's not "true" title case. i.e. In the phrase "WaR aNd peaCe", the "and" part should be lowercase in English. This method would capitalise it though.

Comment: A downvote for posting the answer a few moments after the origional? I was still writing my answer when the accepted answer was posted. !!

Comment: Upvote - actually provided the answer, whereas the accepted answer is just a link. Much appreciated!

Comment: The call to ToLower seems to be required. ToTitleCase leaves the string as is if it is in upper case (at least with the InvariantCulture).

Answer (score 13):

you can just add some exten­sion meth­ods to the String type:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use the current thread's culture info for conversion
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str)
    {
        var cultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        return cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
    }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Overload which uses the culture info with the specified name
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str, string cultureInfoName)
    {
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureInfoName);
        return cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
    }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Overload which uses the specified culture info
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This works

```
public static string ConvertTo_ProperCase(string text) 
{
    TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
    return myTI.ToTitleCase(text.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: actually using this thanks..

Comment: Perfect!. This should be marked as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
public static string ToTitleCase(this string strX)
{
    string[] aryWords = strX.Trim().Split(' ');

    List<string> lstLetters = new List<string>();
    List<string> lstWords = new List<string>();

    foreach (string strWord in aryWords)
    {
        int iLCount = 0;
        foreach (char chrLetter in strWord.Trim())
        {
            if (iLCount == 0)
            {
                lstLetters.Add(chrLetter.ToString().ToUpper());
            }
            else
            {
                lstLetters.Add(chrLetter.ToString().ToLower());
            }
            iLCount++;
        }
        lstWords.Add(string.Join("", lstLetters));
        lstLetters.Clear();
    }

    string strNewString = string.Join(" ", lstWords);

    return strNewString;
}
```