# How can I change character Case?

Tags: c#

how can I change character  case so result be like :

```
"hello" = "Hello"
"hello germany" = Hello Germany"
```

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is there a native Proper Case string function in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004944/is-there-a-native-proper-case-string-function-in-c)

See [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myString = "hello, world!";
    Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(myString));
    Console.Read();
}
```